# How to forbid View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult _Nasljede()
    {
        return PartialView("Nasljede");
    }
```

and Index action load _Nasljede action with javascript so when i put in browser address bar
..domain/controller#nasljede my page is working.(PartialView _Nasljede is loaded in Index View).

how can i forbid ..domain/controller?
is this even possible in mvc?

If you have any question please ask. i dont know if i explain my problem correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15473121/44853

Comment: this isnt working. but thx for the answer.

Comment: my situation is unusual because i want to see a view only if he have partial view (#something)

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't possible with mvc. I solved my problem with jQuery.

```
if (!window.location.hash) {
    window.location.replace("somewhere");
}
```