# assure that the controller method is actually called by ajax or by POST request in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was testing my code, passing the data from the view page to controller create method. I tried to pass the data using `ajax`, but how can I be assured that **my controller method is really called by ajax function and not by POST request method**.

When I change the `url` in `ajax` or pass wrong `id` values as input in `ajax` method, still the controller method is called and also getting back the response message back to the `ajax` function.

Let me show you my ajax code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_submit').click(function () {

            var testModel = {
                FirstName: $('#First_Name').val(),
                LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
                Gender: $("input[name='Gender']:checked").val(),
                Contact: $('#Contact').val(),
                Faculty: $('#Faculty').val(),
                RegNepaliDate: $('#inp_date').val()
            };
            alert(JSON.stringify(testModel));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "TestModels")', /*"/TestModels/Create",*/
                data: JSON.stringify(testModel),
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })

        })
    })
</script>
```

In the above code, I have passed wrong `url` i.e., `url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "TestModels")',` correct url should be `url: '@Url.Action("Create", "TestModels")'` and also the `id` of `FirstName` (First_Name) and `inp_date`  is mistake, still the correct controller method `TestModels/Create` is called and also getting back success response.

My controller method:

```
// POST: TestModels/Create        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult Create(TestModel testModel, string LastName, string RegNepaliDate)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //return null;
                //db.TestModels.Add(testModel);
                //db.SaveChanges();
                //return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                return Json(new { success = true, responseText = "Your message successfuly sent!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            //return Json("false", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My submit button code in view page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>TestModel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    
    // input form

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I was very surprised how this is possible, in tutorials they only show how to pass data from view to controller via ajax but they never show how to check whether its really an ajax call or POST request. Please explain me how to check this. Thank You!!!

Comment: I guess the first clue would be... When you click on your `#btn_submit` button, is the page reloading or navigating to a new page at all?  If so then you're not *using* AJAX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any attribute relating to AJAX to be set for ASP.NET MVC controller actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558758/is-there-any-attribute-relating-to-ajax-to-be-set-for-asp-net-mvc-controller-act)

Comment: Use the `[AjaxOnly]` attribute from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559042/2181514) to limit your actions to be only allowed from ajax calls.

Comment: Looks like you're not cancelling the submit, so you get both ajax and form post.   Instead of `$('#btn_submit').click` hook into the form submit:  `$("form").submit(function() { ...ajax call...  return false; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to @using (Html.BeginForm()). due to this your ajax method did not work.

When you call BeginForm() without any parameters it defaults to using the same controller/action used to render the current page.

Please refer : ([How does @Html.BeginForm() works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744191/how-does-html-beginform-works/16744311))

If you want to call the ajax method then remove Html.BeginForm() syntax